# Как создать собственный контрол на ext.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs

Мне требуется создать поле для даты и времени. Сейчас это выглядит примерно так

```
@X.Container().Items(X.Panel().Layout(LayoutType.HBox).Items(
    X.Label(field.Name), 
    X.Panel().Layout(LayoutType.HBox).Width(200).Items(
         X.DateFieldFor(valueExpression).FieldLabel(null), 
         X.TimeFieldFor(valueExpression).FieldLabel(null))
```

Но это работает не так, как нужно. Я хочу создать собственный класс контрола, который наследует, например, Field. И он должен работать, как обычный, стандартный контрол.

Какие методы из базовых классов компонентов и/или Builder`ов нужно переопределить в первую очередь? И как сформировать верстку собственного контрола из стандартных?